# Complete stream and emit last value

Tags: javascript, rxjs

How to complete stream by condition, while radiating value at which stream completed?

```
const MAX_VALUE = 6;
const competePredicate = data => data <= MAX_VALUE;

let imitationsOfClientConnection = of( 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );


imitationsOfClientConnection.pipe(
  scan((result, current) => result + current, 0),
  // <- what to write here?
).subscribe({
  next: data => console.log(`You won: ${ data } points!`),
  complete: () => console.log('complete')
});
```

Now output to console is -

> You won: 0 points!
>   You won: 1 points!
>   You won: 3 points!
>   You won: 6 points!
>   You won: 10 points!
>   You won: 15 points!
>   complete

What code you need to write that output to console was this -

> You won: 0 points!
>   You won: 1 points!
>   You won: 3 points!
>   You won: 6 points!
>   complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`takeWhile` should do the trick.

```
imitationsOfClientConnection.pipe(
  scan((result, current) => result + current, 0),
  takeWhile(total => total <= MAX_VALUE)
).subscribe(//...
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-aycaxs?file=index.ts

Comment: Did you actually try?